# Total numbers of characters (LENGTH)

Tags: php

I need to show a total of title characters.
$totals only return 0, where do I wrong?

Any suggestion?

```
    $characters_qty = mysql_query("
    SELECT LENGTH(title) AS title_quantity, title FROM orders 
    ");

    $res_characters_qty = mysql_fetch_assoc($characters_qty);
    $totals = $res_characters_qty ['title_quantity'];
    echo $totals;
```

Comment: Ouch, is that the old `mysql` extension, right?

Comment: yes it's old mysql extension yet :-)

Comment: Maybe that column is empty in the first row. Did you mean to only check the first row?

Comment: Does it return something if you run the query in phpmyadmin for example? Because I've tried it and I've got correct return

Comment: I have 418 lines, on line 415 have 12 characters as mysql say when run select directly

Comment: Hey boss, can you post the result of `var_dump($characters_qty);` please?

Comment: resource(27) of type (mysql result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try/use this which at least using `mysqli`. Tested it and it's work.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_password";
$dbname = "your_db_name";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


    $sql = "SELECT LENGTH(title) AS title_quantity, title FROM orders";
    $res_characters_qty  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res_characters_qty ) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_characters_qty )) {
            echo $row['title_quantity']. '<br/>';

        }
}

$conn->close();
```